# How to extract the text from the element using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gettext, webdriverwait, getattribute

How can I get text of this element:

```
<div class="status-value" id="divdoctyp" xpath="1">AADHAAR CARD</div>
```

I tried this

```
WebElement doctype= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divdoctyp']"));
String type=doctype.getAttribute("type"); 
String label=doctype.getText();
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.print("doctype is "+type +"\n"+label);
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract text **AADHAAR CARD** from the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector` and `getAttribute()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.status-value#divdoctyp"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='status-value' and @id='divdoctyp']"))).getText());
  ```